Changing the "Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK" for a facebook app
We have an app that makes posts to a page under a Facebook account. We use Facebook Login to get permission to do so. This app will be used by many of our clients, each of whom gets a subdomain under ihouseelite.com. Since we are using the Javascript API for login, we need to set the "Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK" value. We used to be able to use wildcards for this values ( "https://*.ihouseelite.com), but that has been disallowed. We currently have over 1000 customers, and hopefully will be adding more.
Can we update this value programmatically? I tried using app_domains from this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/#parameters-3

curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID? app_domains=DOMAIN_LIST&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

But that changes the App domain, not the allowed javascript domains value.

I don't think they currently offer a way to do that. App domains used to be enough to allow usage of the JS SDK for login, IIRC - the allowed domains setting specifically for that, is a later addition. But regardless of updatability via API, I am not sure if the field would allow >1k values, even if you attempted to input them all manually.

So you might need to modify your implementation, so that login is triggered from the main domain, and then send users back to their specific subdomain afterwards.

Yeah, I have reworked the app so that the login comes from a single place. Working a champ now. Thanks
